# Importing data from separate Google spreadsheets, custom function with a time trigger

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I would like to import data from separate spreadsheets (A) into one (B), "global report spreadsheet". The latter would aggregate data and present it in a visual form. This data would be numbers, and pivot tables.

I can do it once by using a formula =importrange, and import the data I need. However, I would like to write a script which would trigger the formula to be run and import the data from spreadsheets (A) into (B) in more or less real time. Google sheets offer the opportunity to set a trigger which would do the job.

Is it possible to write a script which would make spreadsheet (B) perform =importrange operations in some time intervals, and import data from separate spreadsheets?

Thanks!

Comment: Would copying a Sheet from SpreadSheet A to SpreadSheet B solve this query?

Comment: I am going to need a lot of different sets of data to compare months, and to see improvements overtime. It is going to be organised into separate charts, so I can't really copy the whole sheets, as the amount of sheets would be too big in the global report one (B). I'd like to import specific cells/pivot tables exclusively.